# PHP Multidimensional array initialization

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am initializing a php array as follows

```
$newArray = array();
$newArray['2014-13-03']['SMD']['ID'] = 5;
$newArray['2014-13-03']['SMD']['ID'] = 10;
```

Just wanted to check if you guys think this is a wrong way to insert data into an array. It is working just fine, but still wanted to check from optimization standpoint

Comment: Perfectly fine and easiest to type :-)

Comment: You are overwriting your initial value because your keys are the same... other from that, there is nothing wrong with setting an array in this way.