# php multidimensional array initialization (2)

Tags: php

I've basically the same question as this: [PHP Multidimensional array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183704/php-multidimensional-array-initialization).

So, considering this php statement:

```php
$a["info"][] = "o";
```

This works fine, however reading the [php documentation about arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), I didn't find anything that backed up the fact that this should work.

By that I mean that the "info" index is not yet initialized before the statement is executed,
and so why doesn't php trigger a warning (I mean I'm happy that it doesn't, but nothing in the doc says it should or shouldn't, afaik).

Therefore I'm concerned that if I'm using this today, someday in the future php will deprecate this syntax and my apps won't work anymore. That and curiosity.

Does anybody know if the above statement is valid php, and if so, what's the "proof"?

### EDIT

Just to clarify my question (because reading the comments it seemed not clear): Where in the php documentation does it say that it's possible to initialize multi-dimensional arrays like that?  (i.e. my question is about finding the documentation about it).

Comment: why would someone deprecate this syntax do you imagine? It's clearly very useful. Mountains of code would likely break if it was removed.

Comment: The proof that it's valid is whether it works or not. If it wasn't valid you'd get a syntax error, or at least a runtime error.

Comment: My biggest concern with using this is more potential future bugs in the code. What if someone creates another array called `$a` further up the code?  So you go from wanting to create a new array to adding values to an existing array, your code stops working and you've changed nothing!

Comment: _" the "info" index is not yet initialized before the statement is executed, and so why doesn't php trigger a warning"_ ... because it creates the index on the fly, just like it would if you assigned a simple integer to that index, instead of another array. Your syntax is effectively just shorthand for something like `$a["info"] = array("o");`

Comment: @NigelRen we don't know if `$a` is already initialised or not. The discussion, if I've understood correctly is about initialisation of the indexes within it, not the array itself.

Comment: @ADyson, it's the same principle.  If this element was created before, you are still just adding values to that element and not creating a new set of values from scratch.

Comment: Really not sure about it being the same as `$a["info"] = array("o");`, if `$a["info"] ` already exists, then it is definitely not the same.

Comment: @NigelRen that would be true of any array. I'm not sure that's relevant to the bit about multidimensional arrays, which is the thrust of the question. And yes it's the same as writing `$a["info"] = array("o")` because the OP has clearly stated _"the "info" index is not yet initialized before the statement is executed"_ . The whole point of the question is they are asking why it wouldn't warn you that this is the case.

Comment: The documentation vaguely hints at this behaviors here: *"If `$arr` doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array."*